# Counting text values in a Access Field to generate a value for another field

Tags: vba, ms-access, text

I have a weird problem I'm trying to solve. I have a table with a text field. In that text field, the same word may appear more than once (on purpose.) I'm not worried about misspellings or variations at this time.

Here is an example...
 The text field is for which college degrees a person has. 
 A sample record might be...
"Bachelors of Science in Geology, Bachelors of Arts in basket weaving, Associates in Science."
 Now, I want to count how many times "Bachelors" and "Associates" appear in this field.
 So there would be two additional calculated fields called "Total Bachelors" and "Total Associates." In this case, they would be set to "2" and "1" respectively.

Is this something that is even possible? If so, how can I perform this in a query?
 Thanks so much for any help.
 Inchman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count a word, you need a public VBA function in a standard module:

```
'--- Counts the number of occurrences of Needle in Haystack ---
' It is always safest to use Variant parameters for functions that called with user data
Public Function CountWord(vHaystack As Variant, vNeedle As Variant) As Long

    Dim sHaystack As String
    Dim sNeedle As String

    If Len(vHaystack) > 0 And Len(vNeedle) > 0 Then
        ' Variant to string
        sHaystack = vHaystack
        sNeedle = vNeedle
        ' 1. Remove all instances of sNeedle in sHaystack
        ' 2. Calculate length difference of original vs. replaced string
        ' 3. Divide this number of characters by the length of sNeedle
        CountWord = (Len(sHaystack) - Len(Replace(sHaystack, sNeedle, ""))) / Len(sNeedle)
    Else
        ' Empty input data
        CountWord = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Then call that function in your query:

```sql
SELECT ID, [Name], [degrees],
  CountWord([degrees], "Bachelors") AS TotalBachelors,
  CountWord([degrees], "Associates") AS TotalAssociates
FROM persons
```

Comment: This seems like it will work, but I'm pretty new with VBA scripts in Access (I'm a lotusscript guy.)  8>)  I was able to create the standard mod.  I'm having a little difficulty with figuring out how the call in the query talks to it.  To make it easier to follow, the I called the standard mod "CrumbCalcPop" and the field that contains the text is "POPHITS".  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The module name is irrelevant (except it must not be identical to the function name), the function name is called in the query, as seen above. The first argument `[degrees]` is the field name.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This worked and I'm off and running.  Now as soon as I can figure out how to rank this answer, I'll throw you some kudos!  Really, thanks, I don't think I could have figured this out without your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution - to create a function in standard module, which returns number of word appearances in string and use it in query field